# How i send data from a controller to site.master C# VS 2008 MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, master-pages

How i send data from a controller to site.master C# VS 2008 MVC

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more detail it's really hard to say what would be best. Generally, however, you want to use the [ViewBag](http://weblogs.asp.net/hajan/archive/2010/12/11/viewbag-dynamic-in-asp-net-mvc-3-rc-2.aspx) (for MVC 3) or [ViewData](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/06/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-3-passing-viewdata-from-controllers-to-views.aspx) (for MVC 2 and prior) controller properties.

Comment: ViewData (for MVC 2 and prior)